# Capistrano still trying to connect to my old repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, deployment, github, capistrano

I have changed my repo to Github.com from Cadaset.com and changed the repository setting in my `deploy.rb` file to my new Github repo.

When I run `cap deploy` it still tries to connect to my old repo on Codaset.com.

I cant find any reference to my old repo so cant see why it is doing this.

I have tried

```
cap deploy:setup
```

that works but then I get the same error on

```
cap deploy
```

Comment: Clearly you need to post your deploy.rb and or your console output when you try to deploy. How else are we going to have a chance at helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to delete the shared copy on your server stored at `PATH_TO_APP/shared/cached-copy`. Remove the `cached-copy` directory and run the deploy again.

The `cached-copy` folder contains a clone of your Git repository. When the clone exists, Capistrano doesn't clone it again and simply runs a `git fetch`.

```
executing "if [ -d /var/www/apps/APPLICATION/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /var/www/apps/APPLICATION/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard HASH && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q git@github.com:REMOTE /var/www/apps/APPLICATION/shared/cached-copy && cd /var/www/apps/APPLICATION/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy HASH; fi"
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue as the OP, but I don't have a cached-copy directory on the server. Any other possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

If Simone's answer doesn't do it for you, you may have to manually edit your `.git/config` file on your server to reflect the location of the new 'origin'.  Have a look at your origin in your application project on your local machine, and mirror the origin block in the `.git/config` in the 'current' folder on your server.  This worked for me.

The origin block will look something like

```
[remote "origin"]
 url = ssh://git@yourgitserver.org/username/reponame.git
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```